# Why didn't the moderator remove the SPAM?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, spam

I have seen an answer which was SPAM.

However, a moderator edited it to

> SPAM content removed

Why wasn't the post deleted too?

First I thought that at that time (the edit dates 2010), he hadn't been elected as a moderator yet.

But then I found he wasn't elected, because he is a Stack Exchange employee.

Had moderators less power back then? Did the delete functionality not exist yet? Or did he only forgot to delete?

Note: I'm just curious, not trying to criticize.

Comment: link would be helpful..

Comment: I would guess that he wasn't an employee at that time. No idea why the post wasn't deleted at that time though.

Comment: @bluet I wasn't sure if liking the post would would seem criticism. ChrisF deleted the post, so it doesn't require further actions.

Comment: @ChrisF Could be that. Is there some list with the Stack Exchange employees, and the date the were hired? Like http://stackoverflow.com/election

Comment: @Oriol - you're asking the wrong person. I'm just a moderator.

Comment: @Oriol There's not. They used to announce new-hires with blog posts, but they've been expanding so much that they haven't really been keeping track lately. But searching for their name on the SE Blog is probably your best bet for finding out when they joined.

Comment: @Oriol There is http://stackexchange.com/about/team, but I'm not positive it's always up-to-date, and it doesn't have the date hired.

Comment: Saw it on the review queue as well... I guess back then when the person edited it he flagged it as spam but the flag somehow got declined, and it just remained there until recently when it was flagged again and appeared in the review queue. 10k-only link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430742/is-there-a-free-version-control-server-provider-for-non-public-projects/2638431#2638431

Comment: Oriol @animuson Or you could look at their Careers profile which states they (Oded) joined Stack Exchange in January 2013 :)

Comment: @hichris123 Wow, according to that page, Stack Exchange only has two female employees that work with code. And over 50% of employee positions are "Career Sales", whatever that is.

Comment: @TylerH - Career Sales are trying to sell Careers 2.0 to businesses. That is where the money comes from (and from some investors).

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Probably **way** more money comes from investors than from selling Careers 2.0 to businesses.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At the time, the user didn't have the ability to delete the post, *and* we had not begun an active campaign to teach users how to better deal with SPAM. *That* didn't really start [until we finally got a system in place to better deal with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam/192847#192847) (efforts on that began around the time I wrote that answer).

The guidance today is to *not* edit SPAM out of posts because it obfuscates the fact that they *are* SPAM in work queues that moderators and reviewers use. It's better to just flag it and move on so that others *clearly* see the text and take the same action. Until hired, Oded didn't have abilities beyond what we give to trusted users prior to being hired, and back in those days, I don't *think* trusted users could more quickly delete down-voted answers.

That wasn't .. known back then, and it was common for people to edit it out in an effort to not let spammers enjoy the weight of a link from the site, *even for a second* - but many don't know that we automatically nofollow them anyway, so there's no harm done by letting them live an extra 30 seconds :)